# Terraform - allow all outbound ports except specific ports?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have this AWS security group defined in terraform:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sg" {
  name = "${var.name}"
  description = "${var.description}"
  vpc_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.vpc_id}"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["${var.ext_blocks}"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

With this configartion, any port can be used as outgoing/outbound. But if I want to exclude some ports, what would be the recommended way?

Let say I want to exclude ports 25 and 465, so I could do something like (instead of using that one egress rule that allows any port):

```
  egress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 24
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port       = 26
    to_port         = 464
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port       = 466
    to_port         = 65535
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
```

But this needs to define specific ranges, which require to define some extra egress rules. Is there a better way maybe? For example where I can define rule to allow all ports and then exclude some?

Comment: Pretty sure, you can't ;-( If you have lots of exclusions, you could write a wrapper script that would spit out the required TF code, but then depending on how many ports, you might end up hitting the max # of rules per SG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example where I can define rule to allow all ports and then exclude some

This starts hitting the limitation of AWS security groups because they can [only specify allow rules and not deny rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules#security-group-rules), and you can [only have 60 inbound and 60 outbound rules per group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html#vpc-limits-security-groups) (total of 120 rules each).

Ideally, you'd be able to define a variable like this

```
variable "excluded_ports" { default=[25,465] }
```

that could then be used to build up [aws_security_group_rule resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group_rule.html) similar to what you posted in your question (i.e from/to blocks of 0-24, 26-464, and 466-65535). Unfortunately, that would be fairly difficult and, if possible, result in an ugly/hackish way to generate the from/to ports based off of that provided variable. This is because mapping over list elements is not currently supported in the latest (v0.11) version of Terraform (ref [this terraform issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16550) and [this one](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17988)), but Terraform v0.12 will make those types of operations much easier.